# How could I verify if google new recaptcha is checked

Tags: recaptcha

I'm now trying to use **new google recaptcha** in my webpage.
In *previous recapthca*, I usually use this script to check if user fill the recaptca challenge.

```
if (isset($_POST['cmdlogin'])){
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],strip_tags($_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field']),strip_tags($_POST['recaptcha_response_field']));
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {// Bila captcha not true
        echo "<script>alert('Invalid! try again!');</script>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=login.php'>";
        exit();
        }
....
```

Then, I found this tutorial [http://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/google-recaptcha-tutorial/#comment-22729, but it did not satisfy me.

Besides, when user reloads the page or time is out, there will be a "previous recaptcha", so how should I handle it then? Otherwise user will reload the page to avoid the previous one. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**:
Ref: https://github.com/google/ReCAPTCHA/tree/master/php
I think this question is now solved. I foundthe link and it gave me full tutorial about using new google recaptcha in php script.

**ISSUE:**
When a user reload the page, there will be an old google recaptcha appears and we do not need to verify the old one since when user type the correct recaptcha, the "RESULT" will be sent to new recaptcha. On the other hand, the focus of the verification is not the old one but still the new one. This occurs to protect it from spam when unknown user uses other bots to attack the new one. By appearing the old one, the attack can, say, get failure.

```
if ($resp != null && $resp->success) {
    echo "<script>alert('SUCCESS Verifying Recaptcha!');</script>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=login.php'>";
    exit();
    }
```

Comment: This code is nonsense, and will never work. `$response.success` will append the word `success` to the JSON response (and generate a warning); the resulting mishmash will never be equal to `false`.

Comment: No, seriously, that won't work at all. Try entering an incorrect response.

Comment: The code in your answer? Throw it away and start over, working from Google's documentation rather than this poorly written tutorial.

Comment: thanks. what you said is right. now I updated for future references. At last, I fix my fault.

Answer (score 8):

`html_element` is the id of my empty div.. Then you can put the following in a function and call it on submit:

```
var googleResponse = jQuery('#g-recaptcha-response').val();
if (!googleResponse) {
    $('<p style="color:red !important" class="error-captcha"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove " ></span> Please fill up the captcha.</p>" ').insertAfter("#html_element");
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if **google recaptcha** is checked or not can be done by the following **javascript** condition :

```
<script>
if(grecaptcha && grecaptcha.getResponse().length > 0)
{
     //the recaptcha is checked
     // Do what you want here
     alert('Well, recaptcha is checked !');
}
else
{
    //The recaptcha is not cheched
    //You can display an error message here
    alert('Oops, you have to check the recaptcha !');
}
</script>
```